# How to add radio button to react-sortable-tree?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-sortable-Tree and I want to add radio button to each node .
I add this code

```
generateNodeProps={(rowInfo: ExtendedNodeData) => ({
                            buttons: [
                                <Radio
                                    checked={this.state.checked}
                                    id={rowInfo.node.id}
                                    onChange={(event) => { this.handelNodeChange(event, rowInfo) }}
                                >
                                    {rowInfo.node.title}
                                </Radio>
                            ]
                        })
```

But I cannot select one radio and de-select the other nodes any suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in this url
`https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs`
I do add this line into `<Radio`  tag

```
   checked={this.state.selectedNodeId === rowInfo.node.id}
```

I hope this helps.